# Do common implementations of mini-batch gradient descent violate the i.i.d assumption needed for unbiased estimation?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, train, stochastic-gradient-descent

When we perform mini-batch GD, we estimate the true gradient:

$$\nabla L = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \nabla L_i$$

with:

$$\nabla_B L = \frac{1}{B} \sum_{i \in B} \nabla L_i$$

where $B$ is the batch size. Notice, that the true gradient can be thought as the expectation value of a uniform distribution ($p_i = \frac{1}{N}$ for each $i$).

One can show (due to the linearity of the expectation operator) that:

$$\mathbb{E}[\nabla_B L] = \nabla_L$$

i.e., the **mini-batch gradient is an unbiased estimator of the true gradient assuming the indices $i$ are i.i.d**.

But in common implementations we just shuffle the training set once at each epoch instead of sampling uniformly (which we could achieve it by sampling with replacement) the indices $i$.

In that case, is the mini-batch gradient an unbiased estimator of the true gradient?

Comment: You don't need to assume the indices are iid. Your data is already assumed to be an iid sample. Eg collect a sample of dice rolls indexed from 1 to a million. Any sequence will give you an unbiased estimate of the mean die value (whether you choose first 100, even indices,...)